# How to initialize something in ApplicationController that's going to be constant?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to do request logging to the database in my application controller. But I want to **not** log the requests made by crawlers. Say I can identify them by their ip addresses. So in my ApplicationController I can create a before filter like this:

```
do_log_request unless @crawler_ips.include? ip_address
```

**Where in the application controller do I initialize `@crawler_ips`?** Say I want to load them from the database as well, but just once when the application starts.

I was thinking about using a class variable, but I get a warning that it's not a good idea to use class vars (which is true). I don't want the `@crawler_ips` to be initialized every time a request comes (this is what will happen, because for every request a new controller is created, right?)

Answer (score 0):

In order to separate most of this logic out of the controller, I'd create a module under `/lib` to handle designated IP logic... I'll call it `SpecialIPs` for reference.

If you want you can create an initializer which sets the crawlers IPs. From there you could write a module function called `crawler?` which returns true if a given IP address is a crawler IP. Now you can call `SpecialIPs.crawler?(some_ip_address)` from anywhere in your app.

If you'd like to alias this into a helper method so that calling this method is slightly easier in your controllers and views, add a helper method `crawler?` which aliases `SpecialIPs.crawler?`. This way in your controller you can simply write `do_log_request unless crawler?(ip_address)`.

Comment: Thx for the answer. How would the initializer look like? By rails helper method you mean a method in ApplicationHelper? I'm still a bit new to rails.

Comment: @vrepsys you could put the method in ApplicationHelper, but it's usually better to split up your helpers so that each helper module contains only methods that are related so I would suggest a new helper module for IP related methods. The helper part is completely optional, though; it is only for convenience in controllers & views. I've updated my answer to elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

To make it very simple, I'd just create a file in `config/initializers` called `my_constants.rb`.  Here you can add any constant you'd like included in the rails environment.  FYI - in development, you'll have to restart the server before changes to the file will take effect.

In `my_constants.rb`, put something like:

```
CrawlerIps = [#include ips as array]
```

`CrawlerIps` will be available anywhere in your application.

This might be overly simple and end up cluttering up your code, but if you need a quick fix this should do it.

Comment: [Use `SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE` for constants](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#screaming-snake-case).